# citing and bibliography format in beamer

Tags: beamer, citing, abnt, abntex2

When I am citing references in beamer they are coming out as listing the author, I just want it to give a number instead. This is the code I am using, and, this is how my references and the citation are currently displaying.

Relevant code in the document for bibliography formatting:

```
%--------------------------------------------%

\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{frame}
\bibliography{document}
\end{frame}
```

I am using a .bib sep file for the bibliogrpahy and it is inserted as:

```
@book{durst2008fluid,
title={Fluid mechanics: an introduction to the theory of fluid flows},
author={Durst, Franz},
year={2008},
publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the code shown so far is not enough to identify the citation style in your document. You need to show us any citation related packages you load as well as your style settings. (This is best done in a fully compilable example document: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: okay, many thanks, I have updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `num` option instead of `alf` for numeric citations:

```
%--------------------------------------------%

\documentclass[handout,t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\usepackage[num]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{durst2008fluid,
title={Fluid mechanics: an introduction to the theory of fluid flows},
author={Durst, Franz},
year={2008},
publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{durst2008fluid}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]